# Error in sqlalchemy. List into integer bug

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to put this list into ID_GENERO table, but i have these error and the code its not working. If someone can help me, i will be glad!
Why i am having these 2 after the list.

Error:

> 

```
  **sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError
>     sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
>     [SQL: UPDATE usuario SET id_genero=? WHERE usuario.id = ?]
>     [parameters: ([], 2)
```

]**

HTML:

```
> <center><h5 class="card-title">{{i.titulo}}</h5></center>
>         <center><p class="card-text">{{i.sinopse}}</p></center>
>         <center><p class="card-text">{{i.id_genero}}</p></center>
>         <form action="/salvar-respostas-livros" method="POST">
>         <center><input type="checkbox" id="male" name="generos" value="{{i.id_genero}}"></center>
>         <center><label for="male">Gosto</label><br></center>
>       </div>
>     </div>   </div> </div>   {% endfor %}
>       <center> <input class="btn btn-default btn-block mt-2 bg-success text-white" type="submit"  value="Enviar" ></center>   </form>
```

ROUTE:

```
> @app.route("/salvar-respostas-livros", methods=['POST'])
> @login_required def SalvarRLivros():
>     request.form.getlist("generos")
>     idezinha = current_user.id
> 
>     usuario = Usuario.query.filter_by(id=idezinha).first()
> 
>     usuario.id_genero = request.form.getlist("generos")
> 
>     db.session.add(usuario)
>     db.session.commit()
>     flash('Efoi')
>     return redirect('/feed')
```

Models:

```
class Usuario(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "usuario"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    apelido = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    senha = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(200))
    id_genero = db.Column( db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('generos.id'))
    avalia_livro = db.relationship('Avaliacao_Livro', backref='usuario', lazy = True)
    avalia_filme = db.relationship('Avaliacao_Filme', backref='usuario', lazy = True)
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the code for the generos model.

Comment: `id_genero` is an integer column. It cannot accept a list.